# Is it ok to shift pipe logic to ngrx reducer?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new to ngrx-store, I just wanted to know whether is it OK to write logic(e.g search logic) inside store reducer instead of pipe itself OR rather just keep them separate, because pipe causes application **state change**.

Below is the small example code snippet. Say suppose, I want to **search**/**filter** todo list on the basis of user input string.

**todo.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../todo.model/todo.model';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class TodoSearchPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(values: Todo[], term: string){
        return values.filter(obj => obj.name.startsWith(term))
    }
}
```

and **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Todo } from '../todo.model/todo.model';
import { TodoService } from '../todo.service/todo.service';
import { TodoSearchPipe } from '../todo.pipe/todo.pipe';

@Component({
    selector:'main-app',
    template: `

        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor = 'let todo of $todoList | async | searchPipe: userSearchInput'>
                {{ todo.name }} - {{ todo.desc }}
            <li>
        </ul><br/>
        Search By Name: <input type='text' [(ngModel)] = 'userSearchInput'/>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    private $todoList:Observable<Todo[]>;
    private userSearchInput: string = "";

    constructor(private _store: Store<Number>, private _service: TodoService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.$todoList = this._store.select('todos');
    }
}
```

As in **TodoSearchPipe** the line `values.filter(obj => obj.name.startsWith(term))` causes application state changes. What if we dispatch event from here for reducer and write this filter line there? Is it OK to do that, if yes how to achieve this?

The ngrx store code snippet goes here:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Todo } from '../todo.model/todo.model';

export const todoStore: ActionReducer<Todo> = (state: Todo[] = [], action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_LIST":return state = action.payload;  
        case "FILTER_LIST": //???????? 
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this in the store instead of a pipe as you are doing by saving the search term and the todos individually in the state. That way you can see in the store your list of todo's and your current search term (thus making debugging easier). You can then select from the store, combine these two pieces of data, and use them in your list.

Something like this.

app.component.ts:

```
    @Component({
        selector:'main-app',
        template:
            <h3>Todo List</h3>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor = 'let todo of $filteredList | async'>
                    {{ todo.name }} - {{ todo.desc }}
                <li>
            </ul><br/>
            Search By Name: <input type='text' (keyup)="onkeyup($event.target.value)"/>
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
        private $filteredList: Observable<Todo[]>;
        private userSearchInput: string = "";

        constructor(private _store: Store<Number>, private _service: TodoService){}

        ngOnInit(){
            this.$filteredList = this._store.select('todos').map(theState => {
                theState.todos.filter(todo => todo.contains(theState.searchTerm));
            });
        }

        onkeyup(val) {
            // dispatch the input's value to the store
            this.store.dispatch({type: 'INPUT_SEARCH', action: val);
        }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Todo } from '../todo.model/todo.model';

const initialState: any = {
    todos: [],
    searchTerm: ''
}

export const todoStore: ActionReducer<Todo> = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_LIST":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: action.payload
            });
        case "INPUT_SEARCH":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                searchTerm: action.payload
            });
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason Lutz, really appreciate your response, I got it. Basically you removed Pipe and used store reducer to handle that logic. On every key stoke, reducer handles the output, which I think looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Jason's answer will work and you could do that.

But how do you display this `filteredList` somewhere else if needed ?

Imagine this "filter" is pretty huge, like ... 50~100 lines or even more. Will you copy it every time ?

You should rather use "selectors" : http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

The idea is to keep your store untouched, with raw data and just set a property in your state with what you want to filter. (for example call it "search").

Then, you can build your selector like that :

```
function getMyComputedData() {
  return function(store: Store<IStore>) {
    store.select(state => state...) // whatever you want to filter
  }
}
```

And in your component just use it like that :

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class YourComponent {
  private computedData$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<IStore>) {
    this.computedData$ = this.store.let(getMyComputedData());
  }
}
```

The selector will be updated every time your store changes (ofc based on what you `select` in your selector) and you can use it wherever you need to.

---

You may want to take a look to :
- A working demo I made on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L7N5J2URYqFHqorXJo5Y) with Redux only to play with [normalized data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) and selectors
- A full demo project I built with Angular (V2.x), angular/cli and ngrx : [Pizza Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync)
(the selector is located [here](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/pizzas-categories/pizzas-categories.selector.ts) and used in this [view](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/features/pizzas/pizzas.component.ts#L26))